# How to get precise results when doing calculations of big numbers in Python?

Tags: python, long-integer

`cc = 400360000000001429876543210`

I want the last two digits to be removed

^-> `temp = round(temp/100)`

I should then expect the `10` to be removed, therefore `4003600000000014298765432`

However, the number greatly changed to `40036000000000144040787968`

Comment: When dealing with long integers, use floor division `//`. The result of your 'normal' division `/` is a float, so you lose infinite precision at this point.